# Stop Text widget from scrolling when content is changed

Tags: python, scrollbar, tkinter

I have a text widget with a scrollbar which looks something like this:

```
self.myWidget = Text(root) 
self.myWidget.configure(state=DISABLED)
self.myWidget.pack()

self.myWidgetScrollbar = Scrollbar(root, command=self.myWidget.yview)
self.myWidget.configure(yscrollcommand=self.myWidgetScrollbar.set)
self.myWidgetScrollbar.pack(side=LEFT,fill=Y)
```

The text widget is updated 4 times per second with:

```
self.myWidget.configure(state=NORMAL)
self.myWidget.delete(1.0, END) 
self.myWidget.insert(END, "\n".join(self.listWithStuff))  
self.myWidget.configure(state=DISABLED)
```

The problem is that when I try to scroll, it keeps scrolling me back up to the top (4 times per second, probably). I assume this is because all content is removed.

How can I prevent it from scrolling automatically, or possibly scroll "back" when the content has changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can safe the position and set it back after an update, like this Tcl code does:

```
proc update_view {w s data} {
  # store position
  set pos [$s get]
  $w configure -state normal -yscrollcommand {}
  $w delete 1.0 end
  $w insert end $data
  $w configure -state disabled -yscrollcommand [list $s set]
  $s get
  $s set {*}$pos
}
```

The Tkinter code would look similar, something like:

```
def update_view(self, data):
    pos = self.myWidgetScrollbar.get()
    self.myWidget.configure(yscrollcommand=None, state=NORMAL)
    self.myWidget.delete(1.0, END)
    self.myWidget.insert(END, data)
    self.myWidget.configure(yscrollcommand=self.myWidgetScrollbar.set, state=DISABLED)
    self.myWidgetScrollbar.get()
    self.myWidgetScrollbar.set(pos)
```

Not sure why the get() in between is needed, maybe to force some lookup, but it works.

Comment: I was pretty sure this would work, but sadly, it did not. It keeps scrolling up to the top after every update.

Also, the get-method randomly raises exceptions, like

"ValueError: invalid literal for float(): None0.0", 

what's that all about?

Comment: By playing around with your solution I got it to work, although the set-method doesn't seem to work too well, when I use the yview_moveto from the listbox however it works just fine. Here's (basicly) the code:

    `codepos = scrollbar.get()`
    `#remove old content`
    `#add new content`
    `listWidget.yview_moveto(pos[0])`

Oh, and the exceptions were caused by a threading problem. Tkinter isn't thread safe and has to be maintained within a single thread, I solved my problem by using widget.after instead of using sleep and putting the function in it's own thread.

Answer (score 1):

You can *jump* to the bottom of the widget after each update using the **yview** method of the Text widget. Also, to prevent frustrating users by *jumping* when they are trying to scroll, you can do a simple check to make sure the scrollbar is already at the bottom (*a.k.a* the user isn't scrolling).

```
if self.myWidgetScrollbar.get() == 1.0:
    self.myWidget.yview(END)
```

Comment: I suggest using `self.myWidgetScrollbar.get()[1]` instead.